# xmlvalue vs XMLAttributeValue

Tags: xml, r

I parsed an XML file using the following code and got the results as below:

```
url = htmlTreeParse("http://www.appannie.com/app/ios/candy-crush-saga/", useInternalNodes = T)
ItemList =getNodeSet(url, "//li/a/@title")


>ItemList
[[1]]
           title 
"Angry Birds Star Wars HD" 
attr(,"class")
[1] "XMLAttributeValue"

[[2]]
           title 
"iShuffle Bowling 2" 
attr(,"class")
[1] "XMLAttributeValue"

 ....
[[15]]
           title 
"Angry Birds Star Wars Free" 
attr(,"class")
[1] "XMLAttributeValue"

attr(,"class")
[1] "XMLNodeSet"
```

My issue is I'd like to grab the names of the game by parsing it. So I tried this code (based on my experience dealing with xmlValue ) -

```
IL <- lapply(ItemList, function(x) c(xmlValue(x), xmlAttrs(x)[["href"]]))
```

But it ends up giving this error :

```
Error in UseMethod("xmlValue") : no applicable method for 'xmlValue' applied to an object of class "XMLAttributeValue"
```

I did extensive googling but cannot find the solution to deal with XMLAttributeValue. Can someone give me a hint and let me know the difference between xmlValue and xmlAttributeValue?

Comment: It would be a lot easier to answer if you would provide a real example so that e.g. I do not have to reconstruct your data. Anyway, without being able to test the case, I would try to `xpathSApply` the function.

Comment: @daroczig- thanks, I put the real website address that will output "ItemList".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the updated question and added example URL!

I think with the `@title` you are already into the attributes, that's why you could not parse the `xmlValue`. What about e.g.:

```
> htmlTreeParse("http://www.appannie.com/app/ios/candy-crush-saga/", useInternalNodes = TRUE)
> xpathSApply(url, "//li/a", function(x) c(xmlValue(x), xmlAttrs(x)[["href"]]))
```

---

**Update**: to filter your results, you might try only `xpathSApply` the "Customers Also Bought" div:

```
> xpathSApply(url, "//div[@class='app_content_section']/ul/li/a", function(x) c(xmlValue(x), xmlAttrs(x)[["href"]]))
```

Comment: oh, that's why I couldn't part xmlValue. Thanks for letting me know! Unfortunately I tried this code before, but it returns other miscellaneous data bound with <li><a href=...>, which I don't need, so I put 'title' after //li/a though..

Comment: @user1486507: okay, I see your point now. What about my updated answer?